# What is the correct interpretation of $f'(-x)$

Tags: calculus

I got a confusion about the notation of $f'\left( { - x} \right)$

Should I understand it as
$$f'\left( { - x} \right) = \frac{{df\left( { - x} \right)}}{{dx}}$$
or 
$$f'\left( { - x} \right) = {\left. {\frac{{df\left( t \right)}}{{dt}}} \right|_{t =  - x}}$$
According to the limit interpretation
$$\frac{{df\left( { - x} \right)}}{{dx}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\Delta  \to 0} \frac{{f\left( { - \left( {x + \Delta } \right)} \right) - f\left( { - x} \right)}}{\Delta } = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\Delta  \to 0} \frac{{f\left( { - x - \Delta } \right) - f\left( { - x} \right)}}{\Delta }$$
and
$${\left. {\frac{{df\left( t \right)}}{{dt}}} \right|_{t =  - x}} = {\left. {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\Delta  \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {t + \Delta } \right) - f\left( t \right)}}{\Delta }} \right|_{t =  - x}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\Delta  \to 0} \frac{{f\left( { - x + \Delta } \right) - f\left( { - x} \right)}}{\Delta }$$

So, these two are different interpretations are different. Which is standard?

---

**update**

Thank you for all answers. It seems that all answers are quite consistent.

Then conclusion is that

$$f'\left( { - x} \right) \ne \frac{{df\left( { - x} \right)}}{{dx}}$$

Though in books like [Richard Courant's "Differential and Integral Calculus"](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=eyC1nk9-YjkC&printsec=frontcover&hl=zh-CN&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) page 90, it states

$$f'\left( { x} \right) = \frac{{df\left( { x} \right)}}{{dx}}$$

Comment: **Tip:** You can use $\LaTeX$ in the title.

Comment: RE your update: there is quite a lot of confusion caused by abuse of notation.

Answer (score 4):

Well, $f'(-x)$ means the value of $f'(t)$ at $t :=-x$. So first you differentiate $f$ and then substitute $-x$. The second one is standard for $f'(-x)$ while the first means $ (f(-x))'$

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(-x) = f' \circ (x \mapsto -x) = \left. \frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dt} \right |_{t=-x} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(-x+h) - f(-x)} {h}$$

Comment: Hi, Kenny Lau. Thank you so much. I want to make sure whether my $\frac{{df\left( { - x} \right)}}{{dx}}$ equation right or not?

Comment: @user15964 it is not right.

Comment: Oh, my god. Then what is the correct limiting process of $\frac{{df\left( { - x} \right)}}{{dx}}$

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misinterpreted. By itself it is right, but it is not $f'(-x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $-x$ is a function of $x$, so let's say $g(x)=-x$ and we get $f'(g(x))$, because we have $f'(\cdot)$ we need to calculate $\dfrac{df(t)}{dx}$ and set $t:=g(x)$ after calculating $f'$.

The first way you showed is calculating $(f(g(x)))'$ and it is equal to $g'(x)f'(g(x))$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example: consider the function $f(x)=x$.

Using your first method, $f(-x)=-x$ so $f'(-x)=-1$. This is not true since gradient of the line $y=x$ is always $1$ at whatever $x$.

Using your second method, $f'(x)=1$ so $f'(-x)=1$, as expected.

The second method is the correct (and standard) one.